# How can I deduce the inner type of a nested std::vector at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming

The other day I asked a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59490698/how-can-i-get-the-depth-of-a-multidimensional-stdvector-at-compile-time) about nested vectors, but I've come across another problem that has me stumped. I need to get the innermost type of a nested vector at compile time so I can use it to pass as a template argument.

For example if I have this nested vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> v;
```

I need a way to extract `int` so I can call a function that takes a nested vector and works on the elements like this:

```
foo<int>(v);
```

Except the catch is this function should be able to work on nested vectors of any depth that hold any type. And when I call `foo` I want the inner type to be automatically deduced for me.

So maybe the call would look something like this:

```
foo<inner_type_t<v>>(v);
```

Where `inner_type_t` is some form of recursive template that resolves to `int` when given `v`.

I assume the solution will be similar to that of the other question but I haven't been able to work it out... I'm still a bit of a novice when it comes to recursive templates.

## Edit:

Here is what I have so far...

```
template <typename T>
struct inner_type
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct inner_type<std::vector<T>>
{
    using type = inner_type<T>;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v  = {
        { 1, 2}, {3, 4}
    };

    std::cout << typeid(inner_type<decltype(v)>::type).name();
}
```

**output:**

```
struct inner_type<class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > >
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Most `whatever_t` types are created by making a struct `whatever` with a member `type`, and then `template <typename T> using whatever_t = typename whatever<T>::type;`.

Comment: I added to the question with my attempt at the problem.

Comment: Another option would be to follow vector's `value_type`, and stopping if there is no `value_type`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@tjwrona1992's solution is ok, but doesn't allow for vectors with different allocators. Also, let's make this C++14-friendly with an `_t` version of the trait.

This should do the trick:

```
template <typename T> struct inner_type { using type = T; };

template<class T, class Alloc>
struct inner_type<std::vector<T, Alloc>> { using type = typename inner_type<T>::type; };

template<class T>
using inner_type_t = typename inner_type<T>::type;
```

Also, for the type name, you should using the `type_name()` function implemented  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/1593077) for C++14 or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56766138/1593077) for C++17.

[<kbd>See it working live...</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11f0905ca6944e70)

Answer (score 7):

Wow I was really close haha, got it to work!

I just had to change the template specialization slightly to properly get the type recursively.

```
template <typename T>
struct inner_type
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct inner_type<std::vector<T>>
{
    // Had to change this line
    using type = typename inner_type<T>::type;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v  = {
        { 1, 2}, {3, 4}
    };

    std::cout << typeid(inner_type<decltype(v)>::type).name();
}
```

**Output:**

```
int
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution that follows the **Bulletmagnet**'s suggestion to use `value_type` member type:

```
template<class T, typename = void>
struct inner_type {
    using type = T;
};

template<class T>
struct inner_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::value_type>>
    : inner_type<typename T::value_type> {};

template<class T>
using inner_type_t = typename inner_type<T>::type;

using VV = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<inner_type_t<VV>, int>);
```

A very good explanation of how `std::void_t` works, can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work). It is used here to silently reject the specialization if `typename T::value_type` is ill-formed.

Comment: Can you explain how the `std::void_t` piece works? I can follow it except for that lol

Comment: @tjwrona1992, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work) for a very good explanation. `std::void_t<typename T::value_type>` makes the specialization ill-formed. It is then silently rejected thanks to SFINAE.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the following primary class template, `inner_type`:

```
template<typename T>
struct inner_type {
   using type = T;
};
```

which is used as the *base case*, i.e., for stopping the recursion – when the template argument doesn't match `std::vector<T>` (see below).

Then, the following convenience alias template just for writing C++14-like trailing `_t` instead of `::type`:

```
template<typename T>
using inner_type_t = typename inner_type<T>::type;
```

Finally, the specialization for `std::vector<T>` – the *recursive case*:

```
template<typename T>
struct inner_type<std::vector<T>> {
   using type = inner_type_t<T>;
};
```

This specialization is matched when passing an `std::vector<T>` as the template argument. Otherwise, the first one (see above) will be matched.

---

To check it. You can declare the following class template:

```
template<typename> struct type_shower;
```

Then:

```
auto main() -> int {
   using type = inner_type_t<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>;
   type_shower<type> _;
}
```

It should display an error saying that implicit instantiation of undefined template `type_shower<int>`. This implies that `type` is `int`.

Comment: That looks like an interesting trick, but when I tried it I get a different error instead of revealing the type :( `error C2079: '_' uses undefined struct 'type_shower<type>'`. Could be because I'm using a different compiler.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 I see. What if you write `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` directly as a template argument of `type_shower<>` ???

Comment: Yeah that spits out a type but it's ugly lol `error C2079: '_' uses undefined struct 'type_shower<std::vector<std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>>'`

Answer (score 1):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_iteratev_f_r), this is a short one-liner (as always)

```cpp
template <typename T>
using inner_value_t = mp_last<mp_iterate<T, mp_identity_t, mp_first>>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E69asc68W).

This is relying on the fact that you only care about `vector`, and the value type of `vector<T, A>` is just `T`. Which is actually true for all the sequence containers (this will work for `list`, `deque`, `forward_list`, etc, just fine. Although for `vector<map<int, double>>` it'll give you `int`).

If we had `vector<vector<char>>`, `mp_iterate` would first produce the sequence `mp_list<vector<vector<char>>, vector<char>, char>` (applying `mp_first` until we cannot anymore, and passing the result into `mp_identity_t` which is just a no-op). And then `mp_last` returns the last type in that list. Which is the type we want: `char`.

---

If you want to broaden to support arbitrary ranges, you can instead use `std::ranges::range_value_t` (C++20) instead of `mp_first`, which is the most generic solution.

Or, if you just care about the nested `value_type` alias:

```cpp
template <typename T> using value_type_t = typename T::value_type;

template <typename T>
using inner_value_t = mp_last<mp_iterate<T, mp_identity_t, value_type_t>>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more general solution. It works for `list` and `forward_list` too, not just `vector`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <forward_list>
#include <type_traits>

//using nested = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>;
using nested = std::list<std::vector<std::forward_list<double>>>;

// primary template handles types that have no nested value_type member:
template< class, class = std::void_t<> >
struct has_vt : std::false_type { };

// specialization recognizes types that do have a nested value_type member:
template< class T >
struct has_vt<T, std::void_t<typename T::value_type>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T, typename Enable = void> struct inner;

template <typename T> struct inner<T, typename std::enable_if<!has_vt<T>::value>::type> {
    using vt = T;
};

template <typename T> struct inner<T, typename std::enable_if<has_vt<T>::value>::type> {
    using vt = typename inner<typename T::value_type>::vt;
};

template<typename> struct type_shower;

int main() {
    using deeep = inner<nested>::vt;
    type_shower<deeep> _;
    return 0;
}
```